# How to past post an XML stream to a wcf http rest service using an HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http

I am trying to send an `HTTPWebRequest` POST XML data to my WCF service.
However when setting a breakpoint in my service, it is hit, but my `widgetStream` is empty when I try to read it.  Even if I read it from a `StreamReader`.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

My WCF service looks like this:

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "widgets", Method = "POST"]
    public void CreateWidget(Stream widgetStream)
    {
        try
        {
            XElement e = XElement.Load(widgeStream);
            //...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

            throw;
        }
    }
```

My client is trying to connect and post an XML resource to an HTTP URL like so:

```
public static void CreateWidget(Widget myWidget)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:29858/myservice/widgets");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    string xml = myWidget.ToXML().ToString();
    request.ContentLength = xml.Length;
    Stream s = request.GetRequestStream();
    StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(s);
    sr.Write(xml);
    sr.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

If anyone could please help that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "widgets", Method = "POST", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare] 
[XmlSerializerFormat]    
public void CreateWidget(XElement widget){...}
```

Try this on your service.  I just ran into a similar issue this week.  I haven't tried using the HTTPWebRequest object but I can post raw XML to the service using Fiddler.

You might need to change Content-Type on the client to "application/xml" rather than "text/xml".